# How can i send feedback on particular email in android?

Tags: java, android

Here i am going to do send my data on particular E-mail.

Data contains name of the sender,email of the sender and message of the sender.
All above information to my mail.

Please, help me to solve out.

Comment: You mean you want for example to click on a button and open GMail editor with pre-filled fields (sender, subject and content)?

Comment: No dude i don't want like this.Look i fill all the information and click on send button. All information i will get on my email.

Comment: i don't want to open a intent.chooser i directly send the email to click on my activity button.

Comment: Is this possible in android? i want like feedback type in many website. Please, help me

Comment: Of course it is possible, even if you need to use external libraries or rely on external services for doing this. An example is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700728/sending-email-from-gmail-directly-in-android-from-my-app-without-opening-the-gma

Comment: ok according to your comment i need a sender mail and his/her password.I am talking about feedback type.In which there is no need to login at any account just send their feedback.

Comment: @MilanGajera If you look at code, there a GMail sender is used and GMail server requires authentication for sending emails. It depends on SMTP server you will use, because protocol doesn't require authentication to be mandatory.

Comment: Another option is that you use a REST service handling email send for you. An example could be [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/). There is a daily limit on free emails (I think around 1000 or more).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this wrapper:

```
public static void sendEmail(Context ctx) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String[] recipients = new String[]{"***your.mail@example.com***"};// Replace your email id here 
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "*TITLE*");// Replace your title with "TITLE" 
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
        emailIntent.setType("***text/plain***"); // set content type here
        ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send E-mail..."));// it will provide you supported all app to send email.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all create the email where you want to get the feedback.
So you have your email and your password.

Then create an activity that contains an EditText with an id

```
 <EditText android:id="body"
    android:layout .... />
 <EditText android:id="useremail"
    ... />
 <EditText android:id="username"
    ... />
```

just follow the link below:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700728/sending-email-from-gmail-directly-in-android-from-my-app-without-opening-the-gma/20379494#20379494)

and fill the following info:

```
            GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username@gmail.com", "password");
            sender.sendMail("Users Feedback",   
                    "User Name:\t"+((EditText)getValueById(R.id.username).getText())+"\n"
                    +"User Email:\t"+((EditText)getValueById(R.id.useremail).getText())+"\n\n"
                    +"Content:\t"+((EditText)getValueById(R.id.body).getText()),   
                    "user@gmail.com",   
                    "user@yahoo.com");
```